# Accessing django crispy form's hidden input field in template

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

My code wants me to set value of hidden input field in template itself. I know that I can set initial value but in my case that won't work as I want data from user side. Is there any way that I can access hiddeninput text field in template?

forms.py

```
class Assigned(models.Model):
   c_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   Name = models.TextField()
   status = models.IntegerField()
   ass_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   Contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.c_no)
```

and I am rendering the form in template as

```
  {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy aform %}
```

Comment: This question is not clear. What data do you need to put into the hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values of fields in a form like so:

```
{{ aform.field_name.value }}
```

If `aform` is a ModelForm that's been instantiated with an instance of the model you can access the instance properties like so:

```
{{ aform.instance.field_name }}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the question isn't 'how to access hidden fields from the template', but how to set their value (from the template).